# Setting different resolution for encoding and display when encoding in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, scale

I'd like to encode a video, say, in 960 x 720 but have video players automatically play it in 1280 x 720.

I know how to do this in 2 steps, by first encoding in 960 x 720 (ffmpeg with -vf scale=960:720) and then modifying the display ratio with MKVToolNix/mkvmerge, but it would be a lot more convenient if I could do it all directly with a single ffmpeg command. Is it possible?

I don't think that matters, but my current code looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -vf scale=960:720 -ac 2 -codec:a libopus -b:a 96k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio -codec:v libx265 -preset slow -x265-params crf=21 "output.mkv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the setsar and setdar [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar) for this purpose

```
-vf scale=960:720,setdar=16/9
```

Since you know the output display ratio, it's convenient to use setdar here, although both filters only alter the SAR.